# How does this regex for FQDNs (excluding.arpa) work?

Tags: regex

I am trying to understand how regex works. I understand it little by little. However, I don't understand this one completely. It's basically a regex for fully qualified domain names but a requirement is that the ending can't be `.arpa`.

```
(?=^.{4,253}$)(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}[^.arpa]$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hU6tP0/3

This doesn't match `google.uk`. If I change it to:

```
(?=^.{4,253}$)(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{1,63}[^.arpa]$)
```

It works again.

But this works as well

```
(?=^.{4,253}$)(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$)
```

Here is my thought process for

```
?=^.{4,253}$)(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}[^.arpa]$)
```

I see it as this

```
(?=
```

Is a positive look ahead (Can someone explain to me what this actually means?) As I understand it now, it just means that the string needs to match the regex.

```
^.{4,253}$)
```

Match all characters but it needs to be between 4 and 253 characters long.

```
(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)
```

Start a capture group and make another capture group within. This capture group says that every non special character can be written 1 to 63 times or till the `.` is written.

```
+
```

The previous capture group can be repeated indefinitely, but it should always end with a `.`. This way the next capture group is started.

```
[a-zA-Z]{2,63}
```

Then as many times as you want you can write a to z with upper, but it needs to be between 2 and 63.

```
[^.arpa]$)
```

The last characters can't be `.arpa`.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: +[a-zA-Z]{1,63} picks up the 'UK' in the google url as 2 char length, but +[a-zA-Z]{2,63} doesn't pick it up because 'UK' isn't between 2 and 63 char length

Comment: it does when i take away [^.arpa] however

Comment: Tested my thoughts and your correct. It's like the [^.arpa] adds an extra char to the string, my mistake in that previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an analysis of your regex:

```
(?=^.{4,253}$)              # force min length: 4 chars, max length: 253 chars
(                           # Capturing Group 1 (CG1) - not needed
    ^                       # Match start of the string
    (                       # CG2 (can be a non capturing group '(?:...)')
      [a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}     # any sequence of letters and numbers with length between 1 and 63
      \.                    # a literal dot
    )+                      # CLOSE CG2
    [a-zA-Z]{1,63}          # any letter sequence with length between 1 to 63 
    [^.arpa]                # a negated char class: any char that is not a "literal" '.','a','r','p' (last 'a' is redundant)
  $                         # end of the string
)                           # CLOSE CG1
```

To avoid the tail of the string to be `.arpa` you need to use a negative lookahead `(?!...)`, so modify just like this:

```
(?=^.{4,253}$)(?!.*\.arpa$)(^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$)
```

[An online demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU6tP0/4)

**Update**:

I've upgraded the regex to rationalise it (i've incorporated also the Sobrique suggestion adding an important details):

```
 /^(?=.{4,253}$)([a-z0-9]{1,63}[.])+(?!arpa$)[a-z]{2,63}$/i
```

[Compact version online demo](https://regex101.com/r/cW7sC2/2)

**Legenda**

```
/                     # js regex delimiter
 ^                    # start of the string
   (?=.{4,253}$)      # force min length: 4 chars, max length: 253 chars
   (?:                # Non capturing group 1 (NCG1)
     [a-z0-9]{1,63}   # any letter or digit in a sequence with length from 1 to 63 chars
     [.]              # a literal dot '.' (more readable than \.)
   )+                 # CLOSE NCG1 - repeat its content one or more time
   (?!arpa$)          # force that after the last literal dot '.' the string does not end with 'arpa' (i've added '$' to Sobrique suggestion instead it prevents also '.arpanet' too)
   [a-z]{2,63}        # a sequence of letters with length from 2 to 63
 $                    # end of the string
/i                    # Close the regex delimiter and add case insensitive flag [a-z] match also [A-Z] and viceversa
```

```js
var re = /^(?=.{4,253}$)([a-z0-9]{1,63}[.])+(?!arpa$)[a-z]{2,63}$/i;

var tests = ['google.uk','domain.arpa','domain.arpa2','another.domain.arpa.net','domain.arpanet'];
var m;

while(t = tests.pop()) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += '"' + t + '"<br/>';
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += 'Valid domain? ' + ( (t.match(re)) ? '<font color="green">YES</font>' : '<font color="red">NO</font>') + '<br/><br/>';
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: Thanks i see where i went wrong problem is javascript doesn't allow negative lookaheads so i don't know how to use it in that situation. Can you give me a example without using negative lookahead?

Comment: Are multiple tests an option? Because honestly, that's the answer here.

Comment: I am basically using it for a html field (pattern attribute)  and using a library that handles the validation make up. I can add a event listener and do this manually but i rather avoid it.

Comment: @jermey: javascript support negative lookahead ``(?!...)``  (it doesn't support lookbehind, positive ``(?<=...)`` or negative  ``(?<!...)``)

Comment: Your right. I read to fast. Thanks for the help. I have all my regex's in one location so it should still be maintainable. I'll select your answer because it gave me what i was asking. But Sobrique gave me a lot of insight as well so its worth checking out as well.

Comment: @Sobrique: i've incorporated your suggestion in my update (to spare some steps). We can use cause the last dot ``'.'`` as a good anchor point to place the negative lookahead. It requires also the addiction of ``$`` to be satisfy the requirements (so its ``(?!arpa$)``). If it was ``(?!arpa)`` it refuses to match also a string ending with ``.arpanet``).

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
[^.arpa]
```

All that says is 'ends with something that isn't one of the letter `apr.`' - it's a negated character class.

You might be thinking of a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?!\.arpa)$
```

But if you're trying to compound multiple criteria in a regex, I'd suggest you're probably using the wrong tool for the job. It ends up complicated and hard to debug, thanks to greedy/non-greedy matching, etc.

Your 'positive/negative' lookaheads are to match a piece of a pattern that aren't surrounded by other pieces of pattern. But that can have some unexpected outcomes if you're matching variable widths, because the regex engine will backtrack until it finds *something* that matches.

A simpler example:

([\w.]+)(?!arpa)$

Applied to:

```
www.test.arpa
```

Will it match? What's in the group?

... it will match, because `[\w\.]+` will consume all of it, and then the lookahead won't "see" anything.

If you use:

```
([\w]+)\.(?!arpa)
```

Instead though - you'll capture.... `www`, but you *won't* match `test` (with e.g. g flag, because the `www` doesn't have `.arpa` after it, but the `test` does.

```
https://regex101.com/r/hU6tP0/5
```

It really does get complicated using negative assertions in a pattern as a result. I'd suggest simply not doing so, and applying two separate tests. It's hard for you to figure out, and it's hard for a future maintenance programmer too!

Comment: I see what you mean. I am currently using/trying to use it for the pattern field in html and i have no other way of doing it then this way to my knowledge besides maybe coupling another event handler that i rather avoid.

If you have any suggestion how i can handle this precise problem would be nice but i get your point.